# How can I align list items with text above?

Tags: html, css

Using invalid HTML I get the look I want, but using valid HTML I don't. Is there CSS that will allow me to configure the <FIGURE> or <FIGCAPTION> to emulate what the <SPAN> is doing?

The way I want it to look is on the left, the valid HTML is on the right.

Invalid HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<UL>
  <SPAN style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; color: lemonchiffon">Color Code Guide</SPAN>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: DarkCyan">comment</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: Coral">processor directive</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: HotPink">#ifndef name</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: PaleTurquoise">library include</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: DarkSalmon">user-defined include</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: Gold">library function</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: DarkKhaki">initializer function</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>user-defined function</LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: DodgerBlue">keyword</SPAN>
  </LI>
  <LI>
    <SPAN style="color: Red">important symbol</SPAN>
  </LI>
</UL>
```

Valid HTML:

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<FIGURE>
  <FIGCAPTION>
    <SPAN style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; color: lemonchiffon">Color Code Guide</SPAN>
  </FIGCAPTION>
  <UL>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DarkCyan">comment</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: Coral">processor directive</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: HotPink">#ifndef name</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: PaleTurquoise">library include</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DarkSalmon">user-defined include</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: Gold">library function</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DarkKhaki">initializer function</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>user-defined function</LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DodgerBlue">keyword</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: Red">important symbol</SPAN>
    </LI>
  </UL>
</FIGURE>
```

Comment: FYI, the [figcaption element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption) is somewhat misused here. It should be coupled with a figure. I would probably just be using a heading element. (And thanks for taking me back to the 90s with your uppercase HTML. :) )

Comment: Thanks. I prefer uppercase tags and lowercase attributes. Makes telling the difference much easier on these old eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding some style to reset default style.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<FIGURE>
  <FIGCAPTION>
    <SPAN style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; color: lemonchiffon">Color Code Guide</SPAN>
  </FIGCAPTION>
  <UL>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DarkCyan">comment</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: Coral">processor directive</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: HotPink">#ifndef name</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: PaleTurquoise">library include</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DarkSalmon">user-defined include</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: Gold">library function</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DarkKhaki">initializer function</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>user-defined function</LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: DodgerBlue">keyword</SPAN>
    </LI>
    <LI>
      <SPAN style="color: Red">important symbol</SPAN>
    </LI>
  </UL>
</FIGURE>
```

Comment: This one is even closer. The "title" text is still not far enough left of the bullets, but this gives me ideas for what else to try. I am accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with dev tools the user agent value

for example, first element under TD is ul or figure. As standard in Chrome:

```css
ul {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
}
figure {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 40px;
    margin-inline-end: 40px;
}
```

So, if you want to keep figure with ul layout, add figure in your style overriding properties which break layout, and add properties needed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had not thought of looking that deep into the default settings of the css code before.

Answer (score 1):

Set UL's `padding` and `margin` to 0. This will remove the spaces.

```html
<FIGURE>
      <FIGCAPTION><SPAN style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; color: lemonchiffon">Color Code Guide</SPAN></FIGCAPTION>
      <UL style="margin: 0;padding: 0">
        <LI><SPAN style="color: DarkCyan">comment</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: Coral">processor directive</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: HotPink">#ifndef name</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: PaleTurquoise">library include</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: DarkSalmon">user-defined include</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: Gold">library function</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: DarkKhaki">initializer function</SPAN></LI>
        <LI>user-defined function</LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: DodgerBlue">keyword</SPAN></LI>
        <LI><SPAN style="color: Red">important symbol</SPAN></LI>
      </UL>
    </FIGURE>
```

Comment: This one comes close. If you look at my code you will see that the "title" text is slightly left of the bullets. Otherwise, this is close.